# How to hide https:// in address bar?

Tags: ssl-certificate

We've got ssl active in our site. Now we want to show www.-----.com instead of https://-----.com/

Could someone please direct me the way how I can do it or any service provider who can do it?

Comment: Based on the post you've made, I would recommend spending some time reading documentation in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) so that you have the best chance at getting your question answered.

Comment: This is a representational aspect of the browser; you can't change that server side. Try it out with different browsers, and see the difference yourself.

Comment: Why do you want to hide ssl, isn't it better to show there is a secure protocol?

Comment: Instead, you should remove the `www.` part of the URL; it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t get to choose how a browser renders the URL.